# Create Easy Tables with Power script

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, offline

is there any way of defining Easy Tables through PowerShell rather than the JS file.?

Any Examples for creating Easy tables through CSV OR Documentation about defining through JS file would be helpful.

Comment: Am trying to Add an Easy Table from Portal. But since the tables have complex relations i needed a programmatic way of creating them through Command line or so.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? And what is an "Easy Table"? Searching for "easy" in the Azure Portal returns no results.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the Rest API to create the Easy table and import data to the easy table. I test it with Postman.

**Create easy table**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/tomtestmobile/extensions/Microsoft.Mobile.Management/tables?api-version=2014-11-01
```

body sample:

```
{"name":"tableName","permissions":[{"name":"read","level":"anonymous"},{"name":"insert","level":"anonymous"},{"name":"update","level":"anonymous"},{"name":"delete","level":"anonymous"},{"name":"undelete","level":"anonymous"}],"links":[],"insert":"","update":"","delete":"","read":"","undelete":"","hasCustomPermissions":false,"extendedSettings":{"softDelete":true},"columns":[{"name":"Team","type":"String"},{"name":"Product","type":"String"},{"name":" name","type":"String"}]}
```

[image]

**Import data**
[image]

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/tomtestmobile/extensions/Microsoft.Mobile.Management/tables/JustForTest3/data?api-version=2014-11-01
```

body sample:

```
{"csvData":"Team,Cover Product, name\r\nCloud,Azure ,tom"}
```

Plesae use the following code the invoke rest API in the Powershell. How to get the authorization, you could refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujzrq8Fg9Gc).

```
  $body = "jsonstring"
  $hdrs = @{}
  $hdrs.Add("Authorization","Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1d...")
  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $hdrs
```